# use jQuery.getJSON() to get object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need help. My code just like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  var setting = {
    check: {
      enable: true
    },
    data: {
      simpleData: {
        enable: true
      }
    }
  };
  var url = "<%=path%>/manageMenu/getAllPersonTree.action";

  $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function (name, value) {
      if (name == "1") {
        $.fn.zTree.init($("#tree"), setting, value);
      }
      alert(data);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

The result of `alert(data)` is `[object Object]`, how can I get the true value of the object?

Comment: data is an object which converted to string yeilds [object Object], do a little bit of investigation first.

Comment: @user1658116: The result of `alert(data)` should be `[object Object]` and there is no surprise in it. Post your JSON and tell us exactly which name/value you want to access.

Comment: careful with this loop, you do an alert(data) inside the loop but the data is never changing. even for the purpose of the demo i would suggest getting it out of the loop. Also prefer using console.log(data), you will see it as a tree inside your console

Comment: @KonstantinDinev +1 for the "bit of investigation first". OP clearly need to explorer his debugger capabilities first if he knows how to use one or even using one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a string representation of the `data` object try the `JSON.stringify` method:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

check your object with

```
console.dir(data);
```

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: OP asks how to check the value of his var, so it's an answer.

Comment: this is an answer. if he does that he'll know how to access the object.

Answer (score 0):

`alert` is a bad debugging tool. It's blocking, meaning your code stops executing until you discard the alert. Try using `console.log(data)` instead :)

For reference, this is a good place to start if you're new to debugging JavaScript; http://fixingthesejquery.com

Comment: Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: Ehm, an answer? He asks why alert(data) shows [Object object], I give him an alternative. Clearly he answered the part about getting the data himself, by actually using the data parameter.

Comment: @user1658116 use F12, the debugger. Firebug or Chrome console depending of your navigator. I hope you don't use IE and you know how to use a console. If not then do some research before coding.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the result to a global var (declare a var just after 'var url=...' for example, then assign data to that var). You can then use Firebug, it shows you your objects (DOM tab), you can browse through them and see everything there is to see.